# Amazon AWS: Can I attach volumes at runtime?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, lvm

I can attach volumes in the AWS Web Console by going to Volumes and attach it to my instance.

Unfortunately the Linux Server does not react to this addition of the volume. Nothing appears in dmesg, fdisk doesn't show a new device either.

Do you know if it is possible to do this without rebooting? Technically it should be no problem, but the documentation of AWS does not say anything about this.

Any thoughts about this? Thank you so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can. Check this:

Before attaching a new volume:

```
root@ip-10-254-158-102:~# lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda1 202:1    0  20G  0 disk /

root@ip-10-254-158-102:~# date
Fri Mar  7 06:40:21 UTC 2014
```

After Adding a new volume of 100GB:

```
root@ip-10-254-158-102:~# lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda1 202:1    0    20G  0 disk /
xvdg1 202:97   0   100G  0 disk

root@ip-10-254-158-102:~# date
Fri Mar  7 06:40:55 UTC 2014
```

I put the `date` output just to show that the volume was attached within 34 seconds, the time I took to attach the volume from AWS Console. (meaning, without rebooting the instance because the instance reboot will definitely take more than 34 seconds :-)  ).

Also, I could finds this new volume detected in `fdisk`

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/xvda1: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
......

Disk /dev/xvda1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/xvdg1: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes   <<< This is the one.
......

Disk /dev/xvdg1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

However, I could not find anything being logged to `dmesg`. But the volume was attached and later I could mount it as well.

BTW, this is was tested on an Ubuntu 12.04 AMI.